# Searching an alternate of LEN() function for optimization in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I am having a query like this

```
SELECT firstName
FROM student
WHERE LEN(firstName) > 5
```

There is a Non-Clustered Index on the 'firstName' column.

It is normally advisable not to use SQL function with column of table in WHERE, HAVING etc, clauses. Otherwise sql server will unable to use indexes.

So is there any alternate way to write this query without using LEN() on the firstName column?

Comment: If `LEN()` queries are common, you could add a computed column to the table and index it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are alternative ways of writing this. For example

```
SELECT firstName
FROM student
WHERE firstName LIKE '_____%'
```

But this is not any more index friendly.

You can create a computed column with `LEN(firstName)` and index that though.

```
CREATE TABLE student
(
firstName VARCHAR(100),
LenFirstName AS LEN(firstName) 
)

CREATE INDEX IX on student(LenFirstName) INCLUDE (firstName)

SELECT firstName
FROM student
WHERE LEN(firstName) > 5
```

[image]

Comment: @Martin: So there is no other alternative except creating a new computed column in the table?

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy - If you are always interested in `WHERE LEN(firstName) > 5` specifically then another way would be to create an indexed view with that `WHERE` condition but this would be less flexible. How often do you need to perform this type of query anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would help:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT FirstName,      
           LEN(FirstName) AS NameLength
    FROM student
)
SELECT FirstName
FROM   student 
WHERE  NameLength > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a CTE might be one option

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT firstName, 
       LEN(firstname) AS NameLength
FROM student
)
SELECT firstname
FROM CTE 
WHERE NameLength > 5
```

Raj